# Why am I getting a syntax error when using ANY operator in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, any

I created a table in psql which is named `restraunts` to show the rest which all friends have gone to. Here is the table (friends and rest are the column names):

[image]

```
select distinct rest
from restraunts
where friends ilike any ('Micheal','Martin','Jack') and rest ilike any ('Ofelia','Casablanca');
```

I run the code but I got an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 3: where friends ilike any('micheal','martin','jack') and rest ...
                                         ^
```

The error shows at the comma.

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: The right hand side needs to be an "array expression" so it should be `friends ilike any(array['micheal','martin','jack'])`

Comment: why do you use ILIKE when the pattern does not contain percent signs or underscores?

Comment: It solved my problem. Thank you so much!! @SalmanA

Comment: Because I wanted to make it case-insensitive when matching names in the list. @FrankHeikens

Comment: That makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your query is the usage of the `ILIKE` operator in combination with the `ANY` clause. You tried to use the `ILIKE` operator with a list of values directly, but this is not the correct syntax

Here is the correct way to do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT rest
FROM restraunts
WHERE friends ILIKE ANY(ARRAY['Micheal', 'Martin', 'Jack']) AND rest ILIKE ANY(ARRAY['Ofelia', 'Casablanca']);
```